# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-request

I have a class in which I am checking user permissions, and depending on them, I return a **list** of results from models. Here is what I have:

```
from AnnualLeave.models import Leaves, RejectedLeaves, Employee

class GetLeaves:

    def get_results(request):
        try:
            if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['SuperAdmin']).exists():
                return Leaves.objects.all()
            elif request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['Admin']).exists():
                return Leaves.objects.filter(employee_id=Employee.objects.get(manager_id=request.user.pk))
            else:
                messages.error(request, "You are not allowed on this page")
                return render(request, 'users/home.html')

        except (Leaves.DoesNotExist, Employee.DoesNotExist):
            return []

    def process_results(request):
        leave_request = []
        for leave in GetLeaves.get_results(request):
            content = {'emp_id': leave.employee_id,
                       'emp_name': Employee.objects.get(user_id=leave.employee_id).user.get_full_name(),
                       'start_date': leave.start_date,
                       'end_date': leave.end_date,
                       'reason': leave.get_reason_display(),
                       'description': leave.description,
                       }
        ....

            leave_request.append(content)

        return leave_request
```

And then I'm calling `process_results` function in `TemplateView` like this:

```
class ProcessLeaveRequest(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'LMSAdmin/process_leave_request.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'leave_requests': GetLeaves.process_results(request)})
```

Here is a traceback of error:

```
Internal Server Error: /lms_admin/upcomingleaves/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\LMS\LMSAdmin\views.py", line 77, in get
    for leave in GetLeaves.process_results(request):
  File "D:\Projects\LMS\LMSAdmin\views.py", line 39, in process_results
    content = {'emp_id': leave.employee_id,
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'employee_id'
```

From what I can see, it is reading the entire webpage with the `request` parameter in functions. Like the `get_results` function is not returning a list, but the entire webpage. I do not understand why this is happening because it was working fine before without any changes.

Comment: add full error traceback

Comment: I have added it now in the post.

Comment: Include code which contains `content = {'emp_id': leave.employee_id,`

Comment: It is added now.

Comment: Maybe it returns an empty list `GetLeaves.get_results(request)` please check

Comment: I tried to print out `GetLeaves.process_results(request)` in process_results(), and it says `<HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">`.

Comment: Ah. This is the fact. It should return a list

Comment: It was returning a list before and everything was fine. It stopped working after a colleague of mine merged their code on Github. I cannot trace the problem back anymore.

Comment: Is something missing here? `else: ...`

Comment: May be. Include else block code. But you can do the try except block code in `process_results` method

Comment: You should not return a HttpResponse here. That's what's causes the bug.

Comment: Else block should return a list. Fix here

Comment: @HåkenLid Yes that was the error. Please post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not return a HttpRequest from `get_results`. Instead raise a [PermissionDenied](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view) error.

```
else:
    from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
    messages.error(request, "You are not allowed on this page")
    raise PermissionDenied
```

If you want to redirect to a different page, handle that in the view. You can capture the PermissionDenied and return the redirect.